# What and Why Java 6 & Java 7?

Tags: java, oracle, java-7, sun, java-6

It's been a while when I received some of the subscription from free resource 
talking about the Java updates and many.

I realized that Sun has been taken over by Oracle.
And so Java is now in their control. 
Last info I received, is that Java 7 is openly released with its API for public.
And I am interested to grab it on! But, here I'm a bit wondering.

Firstly, about Java 6.
It is located on the [Oracle website....](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)
But Java 7 is not stored there.
Instead, it is stored in a different location... on the [java.net website.](http://jdk7.java.net/download.html)

Actually, why is it separated like that?
Wouldn't it be great if Java 7 was already stored at Oracle also?
It is not BETA anymore, is it ?

Hopefully there's a bit of light for me regarding these questions....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java 7 has not been released yet.  If everything goes according to schedule, it will be released in a few days.

Since it is not released, any version of Java 7 you might encounter must be a Beta release, (or worse yet, an Alpha release).  That said, the process by which Java 7 was put together was quite open, which is the reason that you've probably seen news articles about the contents of Java 7, even though Java 7 isn't really available yet.

Comment: "in a few days" - that depends what you mean by "a few days". The planned release date is 28 July 2011.

Comment: In a few days an announcement may be made that it's not ready.  It should be ready tomorrow, but one never really knows until after it is released.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the early access release [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/7-138633.html)

The Open Source project is [here](http://jdk7.java.net/)

Java 7 is going to be released on [28th July 2011](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

Answer (score 2):

Java 7's specifications have been released to the public, but JDK 7 is still in beta under the OpenJDK project.

Comment: oooo ic, ic so then... the JAva 7's Specification that already released to the public... not the JDK yet.

Comment: No, not exactly. You can download the early access release now, there will not be many changes between that and the final release next month.

Comment: JDK 7 has been released on Oracle's download site.